# Prove Limit: $x^2\to 4$, as $x\to 2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I have been shown the proof, but I am stuck, have therefore marked out what I do not understand. The first red mark I do not see where five has come from. Could someone please take me through this step by step?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some informal motivation. We want to choose $\delta$ so that if $0\lt |x-2|\lt \delta$, then $|x-2||x+2|$ is "small."

We have control over $|x-2|$, we can choose to make it small by choosing $\delta$ appropriately. The problem is that conceivably, $|x+2|$ could be large, and spoil things. That is why we insist that $\delta$ will be $\le 1$.

If $\delta\le 1$, then since $x$ is within $\delta$ of $2$, we have $1\le x\le 3$. It follows that $3\le\t x+2\lt 5$, and in particular $|x+2|\lt 5$.

Now the rest is straightforward. We want to make sure that $|x-2||x+2|\lt \epsilon$. The term $|x+2|$ is under control, it cannot get bigger than $5$. So if we make $|x-2|\lt \epsilon/5$, we will be OK.

But recall we want $\delta\le 1$. So we choose $\delta=\min(1,\epsilon/5)$.

Comment: I do not fully understand what you mean when saying that x is within delta of 2. Could you explain?

Comment: That's what $|x-2|<\delta$ means: the distance between $x$ and $2$ is less than $\delta$.

Comment: Of course, I think this is the first proof I have ever looked at! So much fun! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: You are welcome. The same theme will recur, gaining control over the size of a potentially troublesome bit.